# Show only one user that you follow

Tags: laravel

I use this package for follow management, but I'm having a hard time showing all posts from all users that are being followed.

https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow

In particular, the problem is that only posts from only ONE user are shown. So even that 10 users are being followed, it only shows one.

My code is this, I'll do something wrong in the query (first()), but putting get() generates error.

```
$items = Auth::user()->followings()->first()->items();
```

Comment: `user` can  follow `user` ? or `user` can follow `post`?  it should be `Auth::user()->posts()->followers()`

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::followings does not exist.

Comment: `use Followable;` in post model then you can do this

Comment: I tried, unfortunately, the same error

Comment: @Boony what you wan to achieve ?

Comment: The posts of all the users you follow. With my initial code instead all posts were shown but of only 1 user who followed (even if you followed 1000 users).